# HTTP POST with gson generates Internal 500 Server Error

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest, http-post, gson

I am trying to collect a json String from an HTTP POST request using Java Spark as my framework.

The code on it's own is working fine:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String userJson = "{\"name\":\"user\",\"age\":18,\"messages\":[\"Look ma... Gson to Object!\"]}";
User u  = gson.fromJson(userJson, User.class);
UserDAO userD = new UserDAO(User.class);
userD.create(u);
```

However, when it's wrapped in a Post:

```
post("/user", (req, res) ->
            {
                String userJson2 = gson.toJson(req.body());
                User u2  = gson.fromJson(userJson2, User.class);
                UserDAO userD2 = new UserDAO(User.class);
                return userD2.create(u2);
            });
```

I get: 500 Internal Error.

The offending line is:

```
User u2  = gson.fromJson(userJson, User.class);
```

The request is as follows:

```
curl -X  POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name":"user", "age":18, "message": ["Look ma... Gson to OBjectlear!... from the commandline!"]}' http://localhost:4567/user
```

If I remove the object conversion code, it works fine and returns a properly parsed json string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace. Without that we really cannot help.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Ugh... having a terrible time getting a stacktrace out of the embedded jetty server in sparkjava...